# OpenCart- getting blank home page with Warning: Cannot modify header information

Tags: opencart

In Open Cart i am getting blank home page without any warning. When I set some code to display error message it shows be below error message

" Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/XXX/public_html/index.php:5) in /home/XXX/public_html/system/framework.php on line 108"

Please help me with this....

Comment: Usually it's mean that some error has been occurred and those error appear before your framework start to send headers and content. So you have to check this error and fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: I check framework file. On local host it's working fine. But on live server same file having this issue.